# Sending String Array to Custom UItableviewCell from cellForRowAt

Tags: swift, uitableview

from **cellForRowAt** I send the following value

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ProductCell
    let product = productList[indexPath.row]

    cell.productImage.image = UIImage(named: product.productImage)
    cell.productName.text = product.productName
    cell.productDescription.text = product.productDescription
    cell.useGuideArray = product.productGuide // ["auto","moto","truck","industrial"]
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator

    return cell
}
```

when I read the value using print() on the custom cell it always returns []

the way I'm grabbing the data in my custom tableview cell is the following code.

**Does Not Work**

```
var useGuideArray = [String]()

stackview.addArrangedSubview(stackTitleLabel)

    for row in useGuideArray {
        let viewImage = UIImageView()
        viewImage.image = UIImage(named: row)
        stackview.addArrangedSubview(viewImage)
    }
```

**Does Work**

```
var useGuideArray = [String]()

stackview.addArrangedSubview(stackTitleLabel)

    for row in ["auto","moto","truck","industrial"] {
        let viewImage = UIImageView()
        viewImage.image = UIImage(named: row)
        stackview.addArrangedSubview(viewImage)
    }
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
class ProductCell: UITableViewCell {



    let productImage: UIImageView = {
        let label = UIImageView()
        label.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
//        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let productName: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()

        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20).bold()
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textAlignment = .left
//        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return label
    }()

    let productDescription: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()

        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        label.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textAlignment = .left
//        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return label
    }()

    let useGuideStack: UIStackView = {
    let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//        stack.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        stack.alignment = .fill
        stack.distribution = .fillProportionally
        return stack
    }()


    let stackTitleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14).bold()
        label.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.text = "Guida de uso"
        return label
    }()


var useGuideArray = [String]()


    func setupLayout(){
//        useGuideArray.append("auto")
//        useGuideArray.append("industrial")
//        useGuideArray.append("truck")
//        print(useGuideArray)

        addSubview(productImage)
        addSubview(productName)
        addSubview(productDescription)
        addSubview(useGuideStack)

//        useGuideStack.addArrangedSubview(stackTitleLabel)
//
//        for row in useGuideArray {
//            let viewImage = UIImageView()
//            viewImage.image = UIImage(named: row)
//            viewImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35)
//            viewImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
//            useGuideStack.addArrangedSubview(viewImage)
//        }


        var useGuideArray = [String]() {
            didSet {

                // Shows the content of `useGuideArray`
                print(useGuideArray)

                // Cleaning the stackView
                useGuideStack.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })

                // Adding the views
                useGuideStack.addArrangedSubview(stackTitleLabel)

                for row in useGuideArray {
                    let viewImage = UIImageView()
                    viewImage.image = UIImage(named: row)
                    useGuideStack.addArrangedSubview(viewImage)
                }
            }
        }



        let productImageConstrains = [
            productImage.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            productImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            productImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 158),
            productImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 85),
        ]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(productImageConstrains)

        let productNameConstrains = [
            productName.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: productImage.rightAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            productName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            productName.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -25.0),
            productName.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25),
        ]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(productNameConstrains)

        let productDescriptionConstrains = [
            productDescription.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: productName.bottomAnchor, constant: 5.0),
            productDescription.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -24.0),
            productDescription.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: productImage.rightAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            productDescription.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: useGuideStack.topAnchor)
        ]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(productDescriptionConstrains)


        let useGuideStackConstrains = [
//            useGuideStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: productDescription.bottomAnchor, constant: 5.0),
            useGuideStack.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -24.0),
            useGuideStack.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: productImage.rightAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            useGuideStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45),
            useGuideStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -10.0)
        ]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(useGuideStackConstrains)

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }


    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupLayout()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }



}
```

Comment: post cellForRow(_:_:) method

Comment: @SPatel can you please ilustrate a little more, I edited my question with more info to be more clear. cheers.

Comment: @SPatel tried this but no success. let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ProductCell

Comment: You never assigned or appended any value to `stackArray` so it will remain empty.

Comment: @Kamran if I do cell.useGuideArray = ["auto","moto","truck","industrial"] it still sends empty values.

Comment: @Kamran Yeah I fixed that.. if I do useGuideArray.append("industrial") it appears but it does not work when comming from cell.useGuideArray gonna update the code a llitle bit more.and edit the question again,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to add views in the `stackView` when the `useGuideArray` is not assigned with the actual `data`. And from the `cellForRowAt`, it is clear that you are not calling the code related to adding `subViews` again after assigning the `data`. A fix you problem could be to use the `didSet` callback to add `subViews` as below,

```
var useGuideArray = [String]() {
    didSet {

         // Shows the content of `useGuideArray`
         print(useGuideArray)

         // Cleaning the stackView
         stackview.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })

         // Adding the views
         stackview.addArrangedSubview(stackTitleLabel)

         for row in useGuideArray {
            let viewImage = UIImageView()
            viewImage.image = UIImage(named: row)
            stackview.addArrangedSubview(viewImage)
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the code once again. and added your solution. but still no progress.

Comment: You pasted this code at the wrong place. Remove it from the function `setupLayout`. Put this at the class level declaration of `useGuideArray`.

Comment: why simply a userGuideArray = [String]() wont do the work?? why the need of didset {} for that.. thanks! @Kamran

Comment: You are declaring `useGuideArray` with empty data. So when you were not seeing any view because the array was empty. When you are assigning the array with actual data then you need to add those views again because they were not added for the first time as the array was empty.